# Use Int to return specific tuples in list causes overflow

Tags: haskell

The code should take an Int and compare it to the first Int in listed tuple (the other Ints don't matter) so Int x should compare to the p in ((p,q,r) : ys) and return a list [(p,q,r),(p,q,r)] so long as x == p. The code compiles but it overflows when tested and I'm not sure if it's a syntax issue or if I'm not compensating for the full list.

```
listTuples :: Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)] -> [(Int,Int,Int)]
listTuples x [] = []
listTuples x ((p,q,r) : ys)
 | x == p    = listTuples x ((p,q,r) : ys)
 | otherwise = []
```

The test:

```
 listTuples 3 [(3,4,5),(4,3,5),(3,6,7)]
```

Return:

```
 [(3,4,5),(3,6,7)]
```

Comment: `listTuples x = filter (\(p,_,_) -> x == p)`?

Answer (score 4):

This is not “overflow”, it's infinite recursion. note that

```
listTuples x ((p,q,r) : ys)
    = listTuples x ((p,q,r) : ys)
    = listTuples x ((p,q,r) : ys)
    = ...
```

I reckon what you want it this:

```
listTuples x ((p,q,r) : ys)
 | x == p    = (p,q,r) : listTuples x ys
 | otherwise = listTuples x ys
```

As Daniel Wagner commented, a better way of writing this function is

```
   filter (\(p,_,_) -> x==p)
```

Comment: It works but it only returns one of the tuples in the list instead of a list where every tuple x == p.

Comment: It seems to only check the first tuple in the list as opposed to every tuple in the list.

Comment: Well, it's hard to understand what result you want; please add proper complete examples.

Comment: At a guess: they're hoping for `otherwise = listTuples x ys`.

Comment: I added a test case with result.

Comment: Aha, so you want the behaviour of `filter` rather than `takeWhile`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using `filter`

```
listTuples' :: Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int, Int)]  
listTuples' x ls = filter (\(p, _, _) -> p == x) ls
```

Comment: Actually the timestamps suggest _you_ were 5 seconds earlier! Unfortunately though,  both answer don't seem to be what the OP wants...